# Recoding time series data to create time 0 for each individual

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to recode some data collected every 2h such that I find the start point for each ID (i.e. when obs does not equal zero, i.e. there is data for that time point), call it time 0 and then for each subsequent time point is called 2, 4, 6 etc.

For e.g.

```
    ID <- c("f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3")
    time <- rep(c(66, 68, 70, 72), 3)
    obs <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 3)
    new.time <- c(0, 2, 4, 6, NA, NA, 0, 2, NA, 0, 2, 4)
    data <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, time, obs, new.time))
```

Hopefully that data frame works

i have ID, time and obs but I want to create 'new time' -- any help appreciated, particularly a dplyr solution

Comment: ok, have changed to a data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** We define `data` as a data.frame rather than a matrix in the Note at the end and then use `ave` to set the `new.time`:

No packagtes are used.

```
make_no <- function(obs) c(rep(NA, sum(obs == 0)), seq(0, length = sum(obs != 0), by = 2))
transform(data, new.time = ave(obs, ID, FUN = make_no))
```

giving:

```
   ID time obs new.time
1  f1   66   1        0
2  f1   68   3        2
3  f1   70   5        4
4  f1   72   6        6
5  f2   66   0       NA
6  f2   68   0       NA
7  f2   70   3        0
8  f2   72   4        2
9  f3   66   0       NA
10 f3   68   1        0
11 f3   70   3        2
12 f3   72   3        4
```

**2)** or using dplyr:

```
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(new.time = make_no(obs)) %>%
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
ID <- c("f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3")
time <- rep(c(66, 68, 70, 72), 3)
obs <- c(1, 3, 5, 6, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 3)
data <- data.frame(ID, time, obs)
```

Comment: thank you, this works on the practice dataset but not on the actual dataset ... i just get NAs ....

Comment: Note that there is an error in the code presented in the question.  `as.data.frame(cbind(...))` creates a character matrix and then converts that to a data frame. As a result the columns that should be numeric are factor. See the Note at the end of the answer for the correct way to do this.  Other than that it is up to you to either figure out what is different between what you have and what you presented and fix the question since we can't know what you have but have not shown.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a custom function and apply it per group, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x) {
    x1 <- length(x[x != 0])
    i1 <- seq(0, length.out = x1, by = 2)
    i2 <- c(rep(NA, (length(x) - x1)),i1)
    return(i2)
}

#Using `dplyr` to apply it,
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(new = f1(obs))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 12 x 4
> # Groups:   ID [3]
>    ID    time  obs     new
>    <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl>
>  1 f1    66    1         0
>  2 f1    68    3         2
>  3 f1    70    5         4
>  4 f1    72    6         6
>  5 f2    66    0        NA
>  6 f2    68    0        NA
>  7 f2    70    3         0
>  8 f2    72    4         2
>  9 f3    66    0        NA
> 10 f3    68    1         0
> 11 f3    70    3         2
> 12 f3    72    3         4
> ```